# Spatial IQ test puzzles

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

The following puzzles were [created](http://news.generiq.net/LS24/ls24.html) by Robert Lato to measure IQ in range between 160 and 190.

Whats the solution to them?

> You are supposed to draw in the dented boxes what the missing figure is for each of the five puzzles, the small symbols in top left are just the numbering of the test.
>
> [image]

Comment: Extremely hard or extremely subjective? Where did you take these? How is it possible to have IQ test without answer options?

Comment: This is multiple unrelated questions... shouldn't that be closed?

Comment: Extremely hard, they are not subjective at all once you see the clarity of the intended solution.

Comment: @guru, and what about "Where did you take these? How is it possible to have IQ test without answer options?"?

Comment: @klm123 How can you ask those questions without answer options?

Comment: @guru klm means iq tests almost always are multiple choice as they are difficult to objectively score. He, therefore, has reasonable doubts concerning your stated source. I don't really care about where you got it as long as it is an interesting and rational puzzle. This would likely be a good question for you to answer yourself as I've never seen puzzles like that and don't think there is a solution that is not subjective/arbitrary. I would be curious to see the "clarity" of the intended result.

Comment: From here: http://news.generiq.net/LS24/ls24test.html Take item 7 for instance, each circle corresponds to a triangle of the figure, with area and direction.

Comment: @guru I like the edit and the admission that you are not restricting information to us.  Thank you.

Comment: I know this is off topic but why is the numbering on question 20 so different from 10? 10 had a single character to depict it.  Shouldn't twenty be the character for 1 followed by the character for 10 rather than the character for 2 followed by a zero (which is zero's first appearance)?  I was thinking the zero was a single open dot from the puzzle but it is the wrong size.

Comment: @kaine, I think the numbers are just for fun and they contain different patterns. I thing first 10 = (4+3*(3+1)/2) are 1,2,3,4,4+1,4+2,4+3,3+2,3+1,2+1. Then the author must go to 2 digits numbers, and I don't know how to represent 20 here keeping the same pattern, so author probably had to add a new pattern.

Comment: @klm123 the numbering system works by increasing the angle between the upper most pair of lines by 90 degrees such that symmetry is maintained unless they would hit the other pair of lines.  In that case, the lower set of lines is replaced by a vertical pair (superimposed so they are 1 line).  When 10 was reached, the symbol is a V superimposed on a |.  As following these rules would result in a | (the symbol for 1) the pattern became || and they continued from there modifying the second symbol.  The problems are 16-20.

Comment: @kaine, "the lower set of lines is replaced by a vertical pair" sounds as quite an arbitrary assumption for me, but this is an possibility. I don't understand why 8 does not look like 10? And why two small | doesn't create one long |? Why don't you create a question on this?

Comment: Not an assumption.  Happens 3 times from 1-10.

Comment: @kaine What's up with 20? Is that a zero?

Comment: Has anyone figured out 18?

Comment: @carlster numbering system changes slight ly. Yes it is a zero. I think so but im not confidemt enough to post it.

Comment: With only two elements shown the first one could be an AB pattern, but that would be too easy for IQ 160-190...

Comment: I can answer those any way I want with solid reasoning and noone can claim that I am wrong. This is why you need multiple choices.

Answer (score 7):

**There are no solutions.** This test is extremely subjective. For each question, there are no enough information to solve them. See question 1: It is absolutely impossible to discover an objective rule between two *very* different shapes. You need at least 3.

I don't trust this pseudo-test. The fact that is is numbered in a weird and useless way shows that I can't take it seriously.

Or maybe I don't understand it because my IQ is too low.

Answer (score 1):

The third one seems to be rule based but can be interpreted in two ways:

- The square binding prevents movement from the inner four tiles.
- The long line needs an arrow binding or it rotates.

Seeing as the first compares best to the fourth picture the most obvious choice would be the first one. Which makes me think it would be:

[image: possible solution]

**Clarification**

The shape can be displayed in a 4x4 grid in all examples. Seeing the size of the possible solution makes me believe the solution will be a 4x4 grid.

The squares in picture one are in the inner 2x2 block and move away from the center in the next images. In the third picture it would be very likely for these squares to have the position (-1,-1)(5,5). Because of this it would be logical for this to happen in the solution as the fourth picture takes the same position.

The outside half squares follow the rule; if you are not in the inner 2x2 grid then invert your position. If you are inside the 2x2 grid then hold your position for a single turn.

The last rule is that of the rotation through lack of squares in the field. When there are no squares in the field the grid rotates (either left or right) by 90 degrees and squares are created at (2,2)(3,3).

So for the actual solution the half squares would be inverted and moved to the inner 2x2 grid. The squares move to the outside and the center lines retain there position because of the presence of squares.

Comment: Could you explain in more details how you have got the picture?

Comment: @klm123 I added a small clarification, the square binding refers to the presence of squares in the 4x4 grid.